# Парсинг double независимо от настроек разделительного символа (точка или запятая)

Tags: строки, double

Если апликуху нужно запускать на нескольких компьютерах в разных точках мира или же с просто разными настройками культуры -- могут возникнуть проблемы с парсингом...

В странах СНД используется запятая, в многих других -- точка. И парсинг, соответственно в части случаев просто не срабатывает как нужно. Без указани культуры вручную.

Comment: Comma - это по-русски "запятая".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension для парсинга decimal числа со строки(string).

- Не важно число на начале, середине или конце строки.
- Не важно Там будет только число или куча "мусорных" символов.
- Не важно какой делимитер стоит в настройках винды: будет парсить кому и точку в любом случае.
- Возможность задать делимитер вручную.

  ```
  public static class StringExtension
  {
      public static double DoubleParseAdvanced(this string strToParse, char decimalSymbol = ',')
      {
          string tmp = Regex.Match(strToParse, @"([-]?[0-9]+)([\s])?([0-9]+)?[." + decimalSymbol + "]?([0-9 ]+)?([0-9]+)?").Value;

          if (tmp.Length > 0 && strToParse.Contains(tmp))
          {
              var currDecSeparator = System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

              tmp = tmp.Replace(".", currDecSeparator).Replace(decimalSymbol.ToString(), currDecSeparator);

              return double.Parse(tmp);
          }

          return 0;
      }
  }
  ```

Как использовать:

```
"It's 4.45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(); // возвратит 4.45
"It's 4,45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(); // возвратит 4.45
"It's 4:45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(':'); // возвратит 4.45
```